# ng-file-upload with several patterns

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pdf, ng-file-upload

I'm using [ng-file-upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload) and I'm trying upload images or pdf files. I created simple form with file input, but it accept only pdf files. If I change order to `'image/*, .pdf'` it accept only images but not pdf. How can I accept images and pdf files?

```
<input type="file" ngf-select ng-model="picFile" name="file" ngf-pattern="'.pdf, image/*'" accept="'.pdf, image/*'" ngf-accept="'.pdf, image/*'" ngf-max-size="2MB" required ngf-model-invalid="errorFile">
```

Example here 
http://jsfiddle.net/maqbzv15/3835/

Comment: In your jsfiddle I have no problem selecting either a PDF or an image.

Comment: @Sébastien http://prntscr.com/hqj37u

Answer (score 2):

space after comma should be removed `ngf-pattern="'.pdf, image/*'"`

Answer (score 1):

Try below code for upload image and pdf file.

```
ng-accept="'.pdf,.jpg'|validate($file)"
```

and for multiple file you have to set ng-multiple to **true**

Comment: thanks but can't figure out how, looks like it doesn't work. The goal is not upload images and pdf, but only one of them. Imare OR pdf accepted

Comment: You would have to list all possible file types: existing ones and future ones as well...

Comment: yes right from @Sébastien you have to mention all required file type

Comment: @Sébastien could you please provide example?

Comment: [This](http://jsfiddle.net/danialfarid/huhjo9jm/5/) will help you to upload several file with different file type.